# Retrieving a user's google calendar at the point in time

Tags: python, flask, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to retrieve user's current google calendar event (i.e at the point in time). As you can see, I had to make a nested loop to loop through *every* google calendar of the user. Yet, I don't always get the right event. I am not sure what's my mistake nor if there's a better/conciser way of doing so.

```
    utc_dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone().isoformat()
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    events_result =service.calendarList().list().execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])
    Ids = [item['id'] for item in events] #getting more colors because events is not taking the time AlCals is taking
    import pytz
    utc=pytz.UTC
    AllCals = [service.events().list(calendarId=id, timeMin=utc_dt, maxResults=1, singleEvents=True).execute() for id in Ids ]
    calEvent = []
    now = datetime.now()
    for calendar in AllCals:
        for item in calendar["items"]:
            if "dateTime" in item["start"] and item["end"]:
                if datetime.strptime(item["start"]["dateTime"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"):
                    calEvent.append(item)
    now = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
    name = max(dt['summary'] for dt in calEvent if datetime.strptime(dt["start"]["dateTime"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z") < now)
    return {'current event':name}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mention the order to get the events results otherwise it will retrun you the random event. add the parameter `orderBy='startTime'` and if you want to get the number of events from the start date then pass the number in `maxResults`, otherwise remove `maxResults` parameter.

```
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId=id, timeMin=utc_dt,
                                              maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                              orderBy='startTime').execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the line

`service.events().list(calendarId=id, timeMin=utc_dt, maxResults=1, singleEvents=True).execute()`

**`maxResults=1` means that from every calendar you access you list maximum 1 event!**

If you want to retrieve more than 1 event - skip this parameter.

Comment: You're 100% right.. But the irony is that whatever you don't get back the events per the amount of `maxResult`. Ex: when I do `maxResult` 1 i get 3 events back as JSON. My best guess is that it counts "each" calendar by itself instead of total. Thus, if you've 3 calendars, it will take 1 from each instead of only 1 from all.

Comment: This is true - it counts per calendar, but you might still have more than one event per calendar?!